# How to make a hyperlink to all the rows in a particular column of a table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I hope I have asked correctly; I'm a beginning PHP programmer. Here is my part of code...

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project");

mysqli_select_db($con,"project");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"select distinct drug from drugs");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<a href='review10.php'>";
    echo $row['drug'];
    echo "</a>";
}
echo "hai";
```

Here when a list of drugs are displayed, when a user clicks on any drug name, then the details of all the customers who entered the drug name and their uses should be displayed. I am using PHP/MYSQL/WAMP.

Comment: youre always creating <a> with the same href, so it will always point to the same place, you must specify href the same way you specify the link content, any tutorial will guide you there

Comment: You will have to write a lot of PHP files, unless you parametrize your link.
Example: echo "<a href='review.php?id='" . $row['id'] . ">";

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project");

mysqli_select_db($con,"project");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"select distinct drug from drugs");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<a href='review10.php'> '".$row['drug']."'</a>";
}
```